# iphone - block not working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c-blocks

I have a code that I am trying to write as block, for the sake of learning.

I have this NSMutableArray that is a collection of NSDictionary objects. Inside each dictionary there's a NSString object associated to the key "time". I am trying to find if a given time is present on that dictionary. If I was not using blocks I would do this:

```
for( NSDictionary* obj in allTimes ) {
    double aValue = [[obj objectForKey:@"time"] doubleValue];
    if (time == timeX)
        [self doStuff];
}
```

using blocks...

```
__block BOOL found = NO;

[allTimes  enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

double aValue = [[obj objectForKey:@"time"] doubleValue];
NSLog(@"a value=%@", [obj objectForKey:@"time"] );

if (aValue == timeX) {
    *stop = YES;
    found = YES;
}

}];
```

but this is never founding anything. All "aValue" are coming as zero and all [obj objectForKey:@"time"] are coming as empty strings.

Comment: The problem may be you are trying to print double with %@, did you try to debug it?

Comment: Log the obj. Maybe it is nil for some reason.

Comment: @vodkhang, no I am printing the string value, not the double aValue.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw, I have done that. It is not nil.

Comment: in fact I have discovered that the block is not enumerating all objects in the array. It is just doing the first object at every passage... what is more strange than I thought.

Comment: the first obj at every passage? what? it doesn't and it shouldn't. What is the passage?

Comment: Is timeX getting loaded properly in the block? Or maybe *stop is YES by default and needs to be set to NO

Comment: @DigitalRobot: if obj is a dictionary, logging it would also show its contents so you can see if something gets messed up when retrieving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me, what doesn't work for you? Did I do something wrong when recreating your problem?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"hehe" forKey:@"time"];
    NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"hehe2" forKey:@"time"];                      

    [array addObject:dict1];
    [array addObject:dict2];

    [array  enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        double aValue = [[obj objectForKey:@"time"] doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"a value=%@", [obj objectForKey:@"time"] );
        NSLog(@"aValue = %d", aValue);
    }];
```

Comment: sometimes, weird thigns happen